# Is there a way to accept 'Terms & Conditions' in Azure using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure, docker, azure-resource-manager

I want to automate an ARM template that makes use of 3rd-party resources like 'Docker for Azure' using a PowerShell script, but I am running into an issue with getting past the "I agree to the terms and conditions stated above" checkbox when attempting to do so.

[image: Custom Template]

Is there a way to bypass this issue or somehow auto-accept the terms and conditions in the PowerShell script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do that when using automation, the only exception is - Programmatic deployment. Some marketplace solutions require you to enable programmatic deployment to be able to automate the deployment of said solution. This can only be done manually (the irony is strong in this one).

That can be done on the solution page or on the subscription blade > programmatic deployment.

you can use these cmdlets to register:

```
Get-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms -Publisher trendmicro -Product deep-security-vm-byol -Name dxxnbyol | Set-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms -Accept
```

This is the example to accept trendmicro deep security

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is right. If you use PowerShell to deploy template, you don't need click `Terms & Conditions`. You could download template and parameter json file to your local and use `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` to deploy this template with script.

[image]

Use the following script to deploy your template.

```
# existing resource group where you would like to deploy
$RGName="resourcegroupname"
# path to the template
$TemplateFile="c:\path\file.json"
#path to the parameter
$ParameterFile="c:\path\parameter.json"
# validate the template
Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $RGName -TemplateFile $TemplateFile -TemplateParameterFile $ParameterFile
# deploy to the specified resource group
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $RGName -TemplateFile $TemplateFile -TemplateParameterFile $ParameterFile -Verbose
```

Comment: Normally this is what I would do, but I was getting an error claiming that there were validation errors. After configuring Programmatic Deployment as @4c74356b41 pointed out, the issue was resolved.